# MVC 5 get value of CheckBox Checked in controller with Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5, ajax.beginform

I use MVC 5 and I try to get the value of the checkbox checked in the controller but so far it always return null.

Here is my code:

In View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Delete",
                        "User",
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            HttpMethod = "POST",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "table",
                            OnSuccess = "Success",
                            OnFailure = "Fail"
                        }))
{
        <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "User")">Add</a>
        <button type="submit">Delete</button>

<div id="table">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_UserTable", Model);
</div>
}
```

My Partial View

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" namespace="userCheck" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And My Controller

```
public ActionResult
           Delete(string[] userCheck)
        {
            for (int ix = 0; ix < userCheck.Length; ix++)
            {
                // do something with userCheck[ix]
            }
            return Index();
        }
```

My button works and go to the Delete Action but userCheck is always null.
How can I get the value of the multiple checkbox?
Thanks

Comment: `name="userCheck"`

Comment: To clarify Stephen Muecke's comment, you're using `namespace="userCheck"` on the input when you likely meant `name="userCheck"`

Comment: And it can be simply `value="@item.UserName"`

Comment: Thanks, I read my code so many times and can't find this simple mistake!